# Is there an app for iPadOS (or any workaround) that can put multiple pages from PDF in one big board or canvas?

Tags: mac, ipad, software-recommendation, pdf

As the question title said, I would like to know if there is an app for iPadOS where I can put and "clutter" several pages from multiple PDFs on a very big board or canvas and I can freely write on those pages with my Apple Pencil.

Apps like Notability and GoodNotes are only capable to work on single PDF at a time so these are what I am not looking for. I saw LiquidText comes close to this but as far as I saw on YouTube, the app only provides users to grab several portions of texts on a PDF, put on a board, and open other PDFs to grab another portions and make some connections to those previous portions. It is like a hassle to me.

Is there any app that could do what I need? Or is there any workaround to put these several pages of PDF on something first? I also have Macbook Air M1 (Mojave installed).

Thank you.

Comment: Many drawing packages will let you create a massive page, import PDF pages onto them, and then let you draw/write on top.

Comment: @benwiggy Could you recommend some of the packages for me?

Comment: the free Vectornator will allow to import a PDF and places all pages on  large canvas.

Comment: Single page PDFs can easily imported into Apple Pages, just create a document with the desired large dimensions. If the resolution of screenshots is sufficient for your application the whole procedure will be probably much faster - Vectornator and Pages import at the full resolution ; vectors stay vectors, included high resolution images will be imported as so, manoeuvring such documents might be slow if many elements are in the PDF.